# Django: Use text box data and write that text in a file

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am super new to Django and web development. Right now my objective is to create a google like interface and take the text from search box and write it to a file (in other words just want to access text data in the search box). I have created a search page like below

**search.html**

```
{% extends "header.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
        <img src="/static/images/logo.jpg" class="responsive-img" style='max-height:300px;' alt="face" >
    </div>

<form  method="get" action="">
    {% csrf_token  %}
    <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
        <input type="text" name="query" placeholder="Search here..." required size="70" >
        <button type="submit">Go!</button>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'search.html')
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')
]
```

Please give me a hint/example of how to go forward from here ? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using `request.GET.get('name')`?

Comment: @domino Yes I tried that. But as I said I am totally new so I don't know where to use this method. Should I make a new python script for this ? Or write in views.py etc ?

Comment: @muazfaiz no, inside views. I found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FNQxxpM1yOs&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDeA05ZouE4OzDYLHY-XH-Nd) good to get me on my feet with django because the docs are quite heavy when you're starting out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your search field looks like this:

```
<input type="text" name="query">
```

The name of the input is `query`. Since it's a GET form, when you submit it, you must have noticed, the url looks something like this:

```
/?query=<value of the input>
```

The part after `?` is called querystring. For every request, Django maintains a dictionary of the querystring. The `request` object has a dictionary called `GET` for GET requests. If you make a POST request, Django will save the form data in a dict called `POST`.

To access the value of the request querystring in Django, you can do this:

```
query = request.GET.get('query')
```

If it's a POST request, you'd do the same but use the `POST` dictionary this time:

```
some_value = request.POST.get('some_key')
```

---

Full docs on this can be found at - [Request and response objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/).

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    query = request.GET.get('query')
    # do a check here to make sure search_term exists before attempting write
    with open('/path/to/file', 'rw') as f:
        f.write(query)

    return render(request, 'search.html')
```